# How many circles are there on the sphere that pass through both points and are tangent to the circle k?

Tags: geometry

**There are two points and the circle k on the ball surface.**
How many circles are there on the ball surface that pass through both points and are tangent to the circle k if the circle passes through exactly one of the two points?

Comment: There is only one - why?

Comment: The problem comes from the KöMaL magazine: http://www.komal.hu/verseny/feladat.cgi?a=feladat&f=B4590&l=en It seems we have a cheater who asks illegal help for solving the contest problems of KöMaL.

Answer (score 1):

In order to fix ideas assume that one of the given points is the north pole $N=(0,0,1)$ of $S^2$, that the given circle $k$ passes through $N$ and has its center in the plane $y=0$. The tangent  of $k$ at $N$ is then the line $\ell$ through $N$ parallel to the $y$-axis.

Any circle $c$ that is tangent to $k$ at $N$ has to have $\ell$ as tangent there as well, so $c$ has to lie in a plane through $\ell$. Exactly one such plane will go through the second given point $M\in S^2$ and will then intersect $S^2$ in a circle $c$ fulfilling the requirements.

So there is exactly one solution, as announced by Hagen von Eitzen in a comment.